# How to call gdal_translate from Python

Tags: gdal, python-2.7, gdal-translate

I want to make a translation of a grib file to tif with gdal, I use the python script, and I have always error "the specified file not found '

```
import subprocess

src ="donnee1.grib2"
dst ="donnee2.tif"
subprocess.call(["gdal_Translate -of Gtiff -b 1",src,dst])
```

Comment: It sounds like python isn't accessing the folder where "src" (donnee1.grib2) is located. Did you try using a full path?

Comment: normally I have the files in the same directory as the python script,in this case I don't need to put all the way from directory, or not ???

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure if this will fix the issue or not but you can try these commands at IDLE or your python command line of choice.

**Note:** I actually think you should look at the "possible duplicate" link and rethink your approach. It seems to make more sense than trying to call gdal from the command line. I can never get that to work except when using the OSgeo4W command line.

```
import os
os.getcwd()
```

Mine returns this ...
'C:\Windows\System32'\

**This tells me that this is the folder Python is looking in for files.**
In your case, the comment below indicates your system is looking there. Maybe **try** putting the file there or try using a complete path to the file ... something like

```
r"C:\FolderWithFileInIt\donnee2.tif"
```

so then ...

```
os.chdir(r"C:\dev")
os.getcwd()
```

'C:\dev'

Comment: I don't understand , 
I launched the command                 '''''import os
os.getcwd()''''' and I had as a result : 'C:\\Python27'

Comment: what  I should  do after ????